# Why water wont leak out in this case? (Picture provided)

Tags: pressure, water

just curious why the water in the aquarium tank would not leak out as shown in the picture provided below? The question is in the red circle. The water level in the aquarium tank is definitely higher than the hand entrance from what it seems. How they did that?

What sorcery is this?

[image]

Comment: The tank is sealed at the top.

Comment: But still the water will leak out from the hand entrance there right?

Comment: Atmospheric pressure presses down on the water floating outside the inlet (there's a reason it's shaped that way). If water were to flow out of the tank, it would leave behind a vacuum. Therefore, it doesn't leave the tank.

Comment: Refer to this parlor trick for a similar effect: http://www.physicscentral.com/experiment/physicsathome/magicwaterglass.cfm

Comment: @DmitryBrant Any maintenance job would require the staff to remove the top cover right? Or they could just seal the inlet first? Anyway thanks to your answer finally I get it.

Comment: I would definitely want a good reliable vacuum pump (or two, or three) attached to the air space at the top of the sealed tank.  Air dissolving in the water at the access hatch would leave solution at the top where the pressure is lower, gradually draining the tank on to the floor...

Comment: Do you have a link for this video? It is possible that it is photoshopped since I tried to find such an aquarium on the net and none came out.

Comment: Nice question, I like your mentioning sorcery - there's the famous saying ["Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws) and it's nice to see that even nowadays this doesn't need to involve quantum theory or relativity :)

Comment: @User58220 Do you have any illustration for your theory? I would love to see one.

Comment: @anna This is 'River Safari' from Singapore :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably, atmospheric pressure prevents the leak. If, as Dmitry Brant suggested, the tank is sealed at the top, atmospheric pressure acts from outside only.

Comment: Meaning if the cover is removed from the top of the tank. The water will flow out from the hand entrance there?

Comment: Yes . It would help in draining fast, even if there is also a lower drain. (Usually during maintenance some water is left at the bottom so that the fish survive ) A container for water   should be placed underneath of course